# Jquery conditional dropdown validation question

Tags: javascript, validation, newform

I have multiple Sharepoint dropdowns validation but I will show only two on my code. I can't seem to find where the problem is. The logic is if the user choose from any dropdown values <> "yes" then user must fill-out the respective exception multiline textbox.

The first If Else statement is working but the second is not. I appreciate any help.

```
<script>
function PreSaveAction()
{
    return formVal(); //calls the validation on save
}
function formVal() {
    if ($("[title='Acknowledgement']").val() == 'Yes') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if ($("[title='Acknowledgement Exception']").val().length) //checks if not empty use length > X to stipulate min char length allowed
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { //textbox is empty
            alert('Error: Please add the required exception into the box before submitting');
        }
    }
return false;

if ($("[title='Preparation Review']").val() == 'Yes') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if ($("[title='Preparation Exception']").val().length) //checks if not empty use length > X to stipulate min char length allowed
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { //textbox is empty
            alert('Error: Please add the required preparation exception into the box before submitting');
        }
    }

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues,

1. You are returning true immediately after a condition is passed. That prevents any further validations from being run.
2. There is a *return false* statement after first if-else block that prevents execution of any code below it.

Try this:

```
<script>
function PreSaveAction()
{
    return formVal(); //calls the validation on save
}
function formVal() {
    bool validationPassed = true;

    if ($("[title='Acknowledgement']").val() == 'Yes') {
        // return true; // If you return true here, none of the below conditions get validated.
    }
    else {
        if ($("[title='Acknowledgement Exception']").val().length) //checks if not empty use length > X to stipulate min char length allowed
        {
            // return true;
        }
        else { //textbox is empty
            alert('Error: Please add the required exception into the box before submitting');
            return false;
        }
    }

    // return false; // This condition here was preventing the script below from executing.

    if ($("[title='Preparation Review']").val() == 'Yes') {
            // return true;
        }
    else {
        if ($("[title='Preparation Exception']").val().length) //checks if not empty use length > X to stipulate min char length allowed
        {
            // return true;
        }
        else { //textbox is empty
            alert('Error: Please add the required preparation exception into the box before submitting');
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Moved *return false* from here to else block.

    return validationPassed;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried your code but it is nothing validating either dropdown boxes.

Comment: Did you try to debug the script? You might be able to find something there.

Comment: Thank you all for your effort and time. I found a simple solution using the built in validation and using formulas. http://summit7systems.com/part-2-how-to-conditionally-require-data-in-more-than-one-sharepoint-column/

Comment: Yeah that was always there! My bad I didn't ask if you had checked that! You need to post that as an answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: I need to revisit your code since there is a limit of validation using the summit link. I can't debug the script since I am doing this on Sharepoint 365 hosted in the Cloud by Microsoft. Any idea why nothing is validating with your code?

Comment: You can actually debug using the developer tools in your browser. You will need to find this in the page source and place a break point there.

Answer (score 2):

Please mark Nisargs answer as the correct one, as he pointed out your errors.

It is always worthwhile to spend time on simplifying your code.

> I just spent a week bringing the 3000 line iCSR JavaScript library
>   down to 400 lines, code is now easier to read, easier to maintain, and
>   I solved 10 bugs along the way.

*I did not test this code below, beware of typos*

```
<script>
function PreSaveAction() {
    function fieldValue(fieldTitle){
        return document.querySelector("input[title='" + fieldTitle + "']").value;
        //yes! we just killed the need for 90Kb in an extra library here
        //no more code needed to load jQuery on this Form
        //return $("[title='" + fieldTitle + "']").val(); 
    }
    function validate( fieldName, fieldException ) {
        var validated = fieldValue(fieldName) === 'Yes' 
                        && 
                        fieldValue(fieldException).length > 0;
        if (!validated) 
             SP.UI.Status.addStatus('Error',String.format('Please add the required {0} exception into the box before submitting', fieldException));
        return validated;
    }

    return validate('Acknowledgement', 'Acknowledgement Exception') 
            && 
            validate('Preparation Review', 'Preparation Exception');
}
</script>
```

You can add color to the Status message as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408240(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your code but it did not validate either dropdown  when pressing submit.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your code but it did not validate either dropdown when pressing submit.

Comment: Then there is a bug/typo in the code and you have to debug it