# why my jquery is not working to validate my form? PLEASE help

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I have 3 dropdowns with 3 related textboxes combo so if dropdown 1 is <> 'Yes' then textbox 1 must not be empty, 
if dropdown 2 is <> 'Yes' then textbox 2 must not be empty and so on. In addition, am I using the correct .js version? Any help is highly appreciated...

```
<script src="/Style%20Library/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function PreSaveAction()
    {
        return formVal(); //calls the validation on save
    }
    function formVal() {
        var dd1 = $("[title='dropdown 1']").val(), // a dropdown with values YES or No (with exception)
            txtbx1 = $("[title='textbox 1']").val(), // plain textbox that must be filled if dropdown No (with exception)

            dd2 = $("[title='dropdown 2']").val(),
            txtbx2 = $("[title='textbox 2']").val(),

        dd3 = $("[title='dropdown 3']").val(),
            txtbx3 = $("[title='dropdown 3']").val()
          valid = false;

        if(dd1 == 'Yes' && txtbx1 == '') {
            return true; // return true if dd1 = Yes and txtbx1 = empty
        }
            if(dd1 == 'No (with exception)' && txtbox1 !== '') {


    if(valid){
    return true;
    }
// return true if dd1 = No (with exception) and txtbx1 <> empty
        }

    // it is fine up to here but when conditional statements below are added, none of the conditional statements are working including the top of this line

            if(dd2 == 'Yes' && txtbx2 =='') {
            if(valid){
    return true;
    }
        }
            if(dd2 == 'No (with exception)' && txtbox2 !== '') {
            return true; // return true if dd2 = No (with exception) and txtbx2 <> empty
        }
        if(dd3 == 'Yes' && txtbx3 =='') {
           if(valid){
    return true;
    }
        }
            if(dd3 == 'No (with exception)' && txtbox3 !== '') {
            if(valid){
    return true;
    } // return true if dd3 = No (with exception) and txtbx3 <> empty
        }
        alert('Error: Please enter the required respective textbox message before submitting');
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You should use comments to ask for something extra. Editing your question does not do anything ( i don't get an alert, it was pure luck I check this question again and noticed your OP changed).

Comment: As explained [here in a similar of your questions](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176287/jquery-conditional-dropdown-validation-question) make you code simpler; it is easier to debug then. The code you posted above is missing a comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your returning true after each check.

A return means that you leave your code which means that the first time you hit a return no more code is used.

What you want to do is dirty bit handling. Make a new var valid and set to false. Replace the return true statements with valid = true.

at the bottom have an

```
 if(valid){
return true;
}
 alert(message);
return false;
```

UPDATE: Code example

```
var dd1 = $("[title='dropdown 1']").val(); // a dropdown with values YES or No (with exception)
    var txtbx1 = $("[title='textbox 1']").val(); // plain textbox that must be filled if dropdown No (with exception)

    var valid = true;

    if (dd1 == 'Yes' && txtbx1 == '') {
        valid = false; // return true if dd1 = Yes and txtbx1 = empty
    }
    /*
    The rest of your logic should follow.
    Check if something FAILS validation. IF so set valid to false
    */

    //if valid is still true passes validation
    if (valid) {
        return true;
    }
    //if it is not true
    //Fails validation and form is not saved
    alert('Error: Please enter the required respective textbox message before submitting');
    return false;
```

*********** My updates (normsp stuff)*********

```
var dd1 = $("[title='Responsibility']").val(), // a dropdown with values YES or No (with exception)
    txtbx1 = $("[title='RESP Exception']").val(), // plain textbox that must be filled if dropdown No (with exception)

    dd2 = $("[title='General Ledger']").val(),
    txtbx2 = $("[title='GL Exception']").val(),

dd3 = $("[title='Payroll Review']").val(),
    txtbx3 = $("[title='PR Exception']").val();
var valid =true;

if(dd1 == 'Yes' && txtbx1 == '') {
    valid= false; // **return true if dd1 = Yes and txtbx1 = empty**
}
    if(dd1 == 'No (with exception)' && txtbx1 !== '') {
    valid= false; // ***NOT VALIDATING*** **return true if dd1 = No (with exception) and txtbx1 <> empty**
}

if(dd1 == 'No (with exception)' && txtbx1 == '') {
    valid= false; // ***NOT VALIDATING*** **return true if dd1 = No (with exception) and txtbx1 = empty**
}

if (valid) {
return true;
}
alert('Error: Please enter the required respective textbox message before submitting');
    return false;
}
```

************ Finally - Working code *******

```
function formVal() {
var dd1 = $("[title='Responsibility']").val(), 
txtbx1 = $("[title='Responsibility Exception']").val(), 

dd2 = $("[title='General Ledger']").val(),
txtbx2 = $("[title='GL Exception']").val(),

dd3 = $("[title='dropdown 3']").val(),
txtbx3 = $("[title='dropdown 3']").val();

var valid = true;

if(dd1 == 'No (with exception)' && txtbx1 =='') {
valid=false;  
}

if(dd2 == 'No (with exception)' && txtbx2 =='') {
valid=false; 
}

if (valid) {
return true;

}
alert('Error: Please enter the required textbox message before submitting');
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: what did I missed?am using a wrong operator? see note ***NOT VALIDATING****

Comment: @normsp looks like i messed up the logic. I am setting it to fail when it is meant to return true. Change the IF statements to check for the conditions that it fails for. I.e: if(= YES & txtbx1 != '')

Comment: Thanks for this. It helped a lot. At the end, I really don't need to check the "Yes" option - a yes is a yes so I am just checking the "No (with exception)" and required textbox. Right now it is working when it is a plain multiline text but not validating when I changed it to a rich textbox due to the fact there is a code getting inserted <div></div> in the rich textbox so how do I check a rich multiline textbox for null value? I think I have to use trim it but not sure where to add it.

Comment: @normsp there is a couple of different ways to do this. Best things is for you to open a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/ (the QA place for general code questions). You will want to textbox code and your current JS code in your question there